# Exception when trying to create a Timer in EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, timer, ejb

I've just started learning Timers so i Followed a couple of tutorials but while every thing should work fine according to the tutorials I get an exception instead, Here is my code:

The Stateless bean:

```
@Stateless
public class TimerClassingBean implements TimerClassing {


@Schedule(second = "0,10,20,30,40,50", minute="*", hour = "*")
public void goTimer(Timer timer) {
    System.out.println("Inside Timer - printing something");
}

public void printSomething() {
    System.out.println("Printing something");
}
}
```

The bean's interface:

```
@Remote
public interface TimerClassing {

public void goTimer(Timer timer);
public void printSomething();
}
```

The exception:

```
10:15:32,462 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (EJB default - 3) JBAS014122: Error during retrying     timeout for timer: [id=d4c25897-c340-4416-b200-2d22c722481a     timedObjectId=testingTimer.testingTimer.TimerClassingBean auto-timer?:true persistent?:true     timerService=org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimerServiceImpl@5c2594b4 initialExpiration=Thu Jan 23     00:00:00 IST 2014 intervalDuration(in milli sec)=0 nextExpiration=Thu Jan 23 10:15:40 IST 2014     timerState=RETRY_TIMEOUT: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type     mismatch
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:166)     [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at     org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.TimerCMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(TimerCMTTxInterceptor.java:52) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:230) [jboss-as-    ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:304) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at     org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-    invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimedObjectInvokerImpl.callTimeout(TimedObjectInvokerImpl.java:101) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.task.CalendarTimerTask.callTimeout(CalendarTimerTask.java:60) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.task.TimerTask.run(TimerTask.java:132) [jboss-as-ejb3-    7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.0.0.GA.jar:2.0.0.GA]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:34) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:228) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
... 21 more
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Annotation `@Schedule` supports the below two method signatures

```
 void <METHOD>()
 void <METHOD>(Timer timer)
```

Obeying the rule, you are using this code which is ok:

```
public void goTimer(Timer timer)
```

Here the Timer is `javax.ejb.Timer` class. As your code is clean, I am suspecting you are using any other Timer class, like `java.util.Timer` class.

Reason behind the suespec is, I see on your error msg that you got `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch`

Comment: So simple how could i ever miss it : D  , Thank you !